# How do you encode a lw,sw instruction in Mips?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

When i run this file through an executable that converts mips instructions to hex

```
 .text
  lw $zero,0($zero)
 .data
 n: .word 0
```

it gives me 
8c000000

but if i change  lw $zero,0($zero) to this
lw $zero,n($zero)   then it gives me
8f800000

How does changing the immediate change the first part of the output?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`8f800000` corresponds to `lw $0,($28)`, i.e. `lw $zero,($gp)`. So apparently the assembler determined that `n` is located at offset 0 in the global area and therefore replaced `n($zero)` with `($gp)`.

Comment: indeed I used the [online disassembler](http://www2.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) and it returns `.data:0x00000000 8f800000 lw $0,0($28)` and `.data:0x00000004 8c000000 lw $0,0($0)`